# WooCommerce 3 Major update template errors

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, updates

Last week I updated to PHP 7 and I have also updated WooCommerce to 3.0.x.

But after the update I have noticed that the extra fields I had in my user registration were not working anymore. I added those extra fields using WP-Member plugins.

When I further searched on the WooCommerce system status at the bottom of the page I found this errors

> customtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php version 2.1.0 is out of date.
>   The core version is 3.0.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php version 2.0.0 is
>   out of date. The core version is 2.3.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php version 2.1.8 is out
>   of date. The core version is 2.3.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php version 2.2.0 is out of
>   date. The core version is 3.0.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php version 1.6.4 is out of
>   date. The core version is 3.0.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-address.php version 2.1.0
>   is out of date. The core version is 2.6.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
>   version 2.1.0 is out of date. The core version is 2.5.0, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php version
>   2.0.14 is out of date. The core version is 3.0.0,  customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php version
>   2.0.3 is out of date. The core version is 3.0.0,  customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php, 
>   customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/title.php

Could anyone help me fixing these and make my user registration page to appear with all my custom fields

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **WooCommerce 3.0+ is a really major update and is much more strict than before. A lot of things have changed and most of custom code used for WooCommerce version 2.6+ will need to be updated.**

See the related articles to [**WooCommerce Development blog**](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/)

Here in your case you need to update all woocommerce templates in your theme located in your **customtheme** *(folder)* > **woocommerce** *(sub folder)*.

To do that, you will have to replace all listed files from the woocommerce plugin **"templates"** folder to your theme **woocommerce** *(sub folder)*:

```html
woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php                             => customtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php                => customtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php                 => customtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php
woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php                     => customtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php
woocommerce/templates/content-product.php                       => customtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php  
woocommerce/templates/loop/loop-start.php                       => customtheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php
woocommerce/templates/loop/pagination.php                       => customtheme/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php  
woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-address.php           => customtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-address.php  
woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php   => customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php
woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php          => customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php
woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-thumbnails.php     => customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php
woocommerce/templates/single-product/short-description.php      => customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php
woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php       => customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php
woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php                  => customtheme/woocommerce/single-product/title.php
```

> **But keep a copy of that old template before, as you will need to replace in the new templates all changes that you have made.**

---

See this related documentation: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)